# How to compare and recursively modify strings in Bash

Tags: string, bash

I need to write a bash code performing some tasks I am going to explain.
The input: two uppercase strings of same length, no matter
their length is. Es:

```
 CYVFGDDAS -->  string1   ,   unchangeable reference string
 CRFDGVEAT -->  string2   ,   modifiable string
```

I am trying to write Bash code that is able to compare the characters with same index recursively starting from the first position:

```
-- beginnig of the cycle --

if the characters are the same skip any action and go to the
  the next position, 
  
while
  
if the characters are not the same the character of string1
  replaces the character of string2 at that position
  
the new string2 is saved in a file

a substituion code is also written in the same file (I will 
explain this below)

the old string2 is replaced by the new string2 in such a way 
its changes are retained

start anothe cycle from the beginning

------

Repeat the cycle until the last character is processed.
```

So, for the example above, the code should start checking from the
first position where two C characters are placed. They match so no
action is taken and both strings are left unchanged.

Going to he second position Y should replace R in the second string,
the modified string should be saved and written in a text file togheter with the substitution code **YA2V** (**Y** is the replacing character of string1, **A** is a costant character that must be present in all substitutions codes, **2** is the  positional index where the substitution occurred, and **V** is the replaced character of string2).

I am proficient in Python which has a large number of modules for string manipulation but because the code should be added to a pre-existing Bash program I need to get this done in Bash environment (builtin commands, awk, sed etc, does not matter). Looks to me that Bash does not have an extended arsenal of tools like Python, so I am first of all wondering if this project is feasible or not.

However, what I tried so far is to convert the strings in blank
separated fields by inserting spaces between the characters in such
a way awk can deal better with them as fields but I did not go very
far with this.
Sorry for the lengthy explanation. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean **YA2R**?

Comment: I don't see any recursion, just iteration

Comment: This is possible in bash. Right now, your question might seem to you like one question ("how do I accomplish my task") but to everyone else, it seems like a lot of questions ("How do I save to a file in bash?" "How do I compare strings in bash?" "How do I write a loop in bash?" "How do I replace one character of a string in bash?"). You should close or edit this question and ask a small, focused question (make sure to check if it's a duplicate!), and show what you've tried.

Comment: @choroba . Yes, YA2R. Sorry for the mistake. I tryed your solution and it works. However, I was thinking about a recursive solution because allows an easier inline processing of each of string2 and substitution code pairs by the following programs lines. As I said,  the question deals with a small part of a much larger bioinformatic program. In this respect, saving the output data is not mandatory but useful for both debug and furter processing. Anyway, I upvoted your answer as useful. Thanks for your support.

Comment: @jeremysprofile, I believe there is nothing wrong asking about the whole task instead of issuing separate questions. This is a real life need for work not just a coding exercize. Please avoid unhelpful comments.

Comment: @choroba . I am wondering if you could explain how the for loop works and, in particular what the last digits :1 stand for in `${s1:i:1}`

Comment: @MaurizioCirilli: You probably wanted to ask under my answer, not here. Nevertheless, I added an explanation.

Comment: @MaurizioCirilli, I disagree. [You can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) that "This question currently includes multiple questions in one" is a valid reason to close a question. The fact that 3 people voted on my comment means people agree. Someone answering a question is only a weak signal of that question being good. StackOverflow is fundamentally about helping programmers help themselves. [It is not supposed to be a "code my task for me" style of site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308837/make-it-easier-to-close-job-shop-gimme-teh-codez-questions/308844)

Comment: @jeremysprofile, I disagree with you, I did not ask to code my task for me, this is a wrong and rude interpretation  of my message. Then, invocking the closure of this post is completely inappropriate to me. Only the moderator has the responsibility to make such judgement . Again, try to contribute with helpful comments, if you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No recursion is needed, just iterate over the strings. You can use parameter expansion with a for loop:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s1=CYVFGDDAS
s2=CRFDGVEAT

for ((i=0; i<${#s1} ; ++i)) ; do
    if [[ ${s1:i:1} != ${s2:i:1} ]] ; then
        printf '%s\n' "${s1:0:i+1}${s2:i+1}"
        printf '%s\n' "${s1:i:1}A$((i+1))${s2:i:1}"
    fi
done
```

${s1:i:1} means *extract the substring of `$s1` from position `$i` of length 1*. If the length is omitted, it extracts as much as it can.

It just outputs the strings, redirect them to files as you need.

```
CYFDGVEAT
YA2R
CYVDGVEAT
VA3F
CYVFGVEAT
FA4D
CYVFGDEAT
DA6V
CYVFGDDAT
DA7E
CYVFGDDAS
SA9T
```